# Computing $\omega^{3n/2 + 1} + \omega$ for root of unity $\omega$

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm trying to compute

$$
\omega^{3n/2 + 1} + \omega
$$

where $\omega$ is one of the $n^{th}$ roots of unity where $n$ is a multiple of $4$. Could anyone demonstrate how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

$$\omega^{\frac{3\cdot4k}2+1}=\omega^{6k+1}=\omega^{4k}\omega^{2k+1}=\omega^{2k+1}$$

If $\;\omega\;$ is a *primitive* roots of order $\;n=4k\;$ , then $\;\omega^{2k}=-1\;$ (why?) , so

$$\omega^{3n/2 +1}+\omega=0$$

Comment: Why can't $\omega^{2k}$ be equal to $1$? Also, I never said that $\omega$ is a primitive root -- we can't assume that.

Comment: If you can't assume that then I think the answer may vary. For example, with $\;n=4\;$ , take $\;\omega=1\;$ , and then $$\omega^{6+1}+\omega=1+1=2$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $n=4k$ we can write the expression as $ \omega ^{2k+1}+\omega=\omega(1+\omega^{2k})$. But now $\omega ^{2k}$ is a square root of $1 $ not equal to $1$. So it is definitely $-1$. Hence the expression is 0.

Comment: How do you know that $\omega^{2k} \neq 1$?

Comment: @Ryan then there will not be any fixed answer that is why I assumed $\omega$ is a primitive root